# redirect subdirectory to subdomain.subdomain.domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

i wanted to change the url for my subdirectory from "subdomain1.main.com/subdirectory" to "subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.com"

i tried the htaccess code below but it doesnt work. can someone please help?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ http://subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain2.\subdomain1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain1\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ http://subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2\.subdomain1\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you Prabhjot Singh.
the issue is that i dont have specific htaccess for these subdirectories. the pages are on Vu Js
the home page is on a subdomain, and other pages are shown as subdirectories. 

subdomain.domain.com/directory

meaning i only have one htaccess for the all the webpages.